# Cost of a reference to reference static_cast and a pointer to pointer static_cast

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Does reference to reference static_cast has the same run time cost as pointer to pointer static_cast?

E.g.

```
class B;
class A: public class B;

A obj;
A& ref = obj;
A* ptr = &obj;

// 1
static_cast<B&>(ref);
// 2
static_cast<B*>(ptr);
```

Comment: If you start worrying about this, then you have gone a few steps to far with your *premature optimizations*. Concentrate on making good, readable, well-documented, maintianable and working code. Then you test your application, and if it doesn't live up to possible performance requirements (and remember that "good enough" often is good enough) then you measure, profile and benchmark to find the hot-spots and bottle-necks, and concentrate your optimization efforts on those only, remembering to document it all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they do not always have the same cost. With optimizations turned on, they always have the same or *very nearly* the same cost.

If you are casting up or down an inheritance hierarchy in which either

- multiple inheritance is involved, or
- a polymorphic class inherits from a non-polymorphic class,

Then a `static_cast` of a pointer may incur the cost of a [conditional move](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predication_(computer_architecture)) instruction whereas a `static_cast` of a reference will not.

This is because a base class subobject might not have the same address as its complete object in these cases, so the `static_cast` may involve applying an offset: adding or subtracting a constant to or from the address of the source type object to compute the address of the destination type object.

Pointers can be null, and a `static_cast` of a null pointer must produce a null pointer, so if the pointer is null then the offset will not be applied. This means that the compiler must use a conditional move instruction to choose whether or not to apply the offset depending on whether or not the pointer is null.

References can not be null, so no conditional move is needed for a `static_cast` of a reference. Also the `this` pointer is immune, as the `this` pointer can never be null.

Note that this also affects implicit derived-to-base conversions, not just explicit `static_cast`.

The cost of a conditional move can usually be ignored. If the code is more readable or expressive using pointers then use pointers. Harming your code for the sake of avoiding a conditional move would almost always be very foolish.

---

Example:

```
struct A { int a; };
struct B { int b; };
struct C : A, B { int c; };

B* cast(C* ptr) { return ptr; }
B& cast(C& ref) { return ref; }
```

Compiler output: (latest GCC with `-O2`)

```
cast(C*):
        leaq    4(%rdi), %rax
        testq   %rdi, %rdi
        movl    $0, %edx
        cmove   %rdx, %rax
        ret
cast(C&):
        leaq    4(%rdi), %rax
        ret
```

---

Note also that most compilers are smart enough to omit the conditional move if they can prove that the pointer can never be null. For example, if we insert `int x = ptr->c;` before `return ptr;` then the compiler will see the pointer indirection and will assume it can never null, because if it were null then the program has undefined behaviour anyway, so it wouldn't matter if an offset were applied to a null pointer. The code generated in that case would be the same as for a cast of a reference.

Answer (score 1):

It does - and you can safely assume that cost in both cases is null. The only trace of `static_cast` in resulting assembly (tested with MSVC++) is an extra pointer copy, and even that is optimized away with any optimization enabled.

Comment: It depends on the object hierarchy, some runtime pointer arithmetic may be needed in cases of multiple inheritance